# can we use unix variables in our property file in java

Tags: java, variables, unix, properties

In java application I have my properties file which has key/pair values like

usa.national.bank=Bank of America

etc.

Now let's say I deploy my app in a unix box, where I already have variables declared like:
export US_NAT_BANK=Bank of America

SO my app is supposed to run in this unix box and at run time at some point, it will read this value.

So tried declaring my properties file like this:
usa.national.bank=$US_NAT_BANK

but it is not able to read the value defined in variable i.e. "Bank of America", instead it reads the literal value i.e. "$US_NAT_BANK"

AM I doing something wrong or is it not possible to use unix variables in property files?

Comment: Not natively; Java is not a shell. But you could certainly use `System.getenv("US_NAT_BANK")` directly, or write your own logic to search for substrings with `$` in them and do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Elliott. So these other solutions obviously will  have to written in java itself and overall, the property file can't directly refer to a variable. Am I right?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Unix variable"; you seem to be talking about _environment variables_ (which are also available on Windows). Are you using Spring? It has built-in support for being able to read properties from the environment.

Comment: No I am not using Spring. My actual scenario refers to a file path. The file is kept at some location on server and my property file is supposed to have this value. The file path is available as a variable on server, but I am not able to use the variable in my property file. Only the hard coded path works.  BTW property is ssl.truststore.location for Kafka consumer

Answer (score 0):

Java has API to interact with System commands using `ProcessBuilder`.

You can use following solution to read UNIX properties using java :

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $US_NAT_BANK");
    final Process process = processBuilder.start();
    try (InputStream is = process.getInputStream()) {
        byte[] result = is.readAllBytes();
        System.out.println(new String(result, UTF_8));
    }
```

Using `ProcessBuilder` you can execute any UNIX supported commands and get same results as you get in console/terminal.

You can more details : [ProcessBuilder JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: That's a convoluted way to read the value of `System.getenv"("US_NAT_BANK")`.